# PLSQL - Duplicate records. Tried unique/distinct but didn't work

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you get unique record of each row based on specified columns? I used both unique and distinct, and the query ran for more than an hour before I killed it. In the actual query, I have joined to 5 additional tables each of which has millions of rows.

Suppose I have

```
ID | Name | Date1    | Date2
1  | Jen  | 1/1/2011 | 1/1/2011
1  | Jen  | 1/1/2011 | 1/1/2011
1  | Jen  | 1/2/2011 | 1/3/2011
2  | Ann  | 1/2/2011 | 1/3/2011
2  | Ann  | 1/2/2011 | 1/3/2011
```

How do I get:

```
ID | Name | Date1    | Date2
1  | Jen  | 1/1/2011 | 1/1/2011
1  | Jen  | 1/2/2011 | 1/3/2011
2  | Ann  | 1/2/2011 | 1/3/2011
```

Comment: It appears that you have a performance problem not that you are struggling with how to eliminate duplicates.  You know how to eliminate duplicates.  Help us out by posting a reproducible test case.  Do you need all 5 tables?  Or is 1 or 2 tables sufficient?  What is the query plan?  What indexes are available?  How many rows will your query return?  How much PGA space do you have for sorts?

Comment: If removing the `DISTINCT`/`UNIQUE` makes your query _faster_, It is the `PGA` as Justin says, as it is going to sort it in memory. Sometimes, a _normalised_ design with perfect joins(index for performance), don't need the `DISTINCT` in `SELECT`.

Comment: Another reason for this could be that the conditions in your joins do not create unique links. This results in the results being duplicated. If original data is not duplicated but the result of the query produces duplicates you need to fix the JOIN conditions. One of the ways to fix it is to remove JOINED tables one by one to see if the duplication is gone. Then you need to understand the link between tables and include the proper conditions in your `ON` clauses

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a group by clause for these columns to get an unique result. It is not a perfect solution, but maybe can help solve your problem temporary.

Answer (score 0):

your question consist of 2 parts (as already noted )
1. performance problem
2. distinct problem

Performance problem potential causes already noted in comments!
To the second part:

```
select distinct t.* from your_table t;
```

or if table large - distinct will have to do a lot of sorting....

```
select c1, c2, ... <some other column(s)>
from your_table t1 
where rowid in
(select max(rowid) from your_table  t2 where t1.c1 = t2.c1 and t1.c2 = t2.c2 );
```

C1, C2, ... your dups columns